# Is there a way to Divide two 8 bit number in PIC 18fXXX assembly language not C?

Tags: pic, programming, assembly, math, mplab

I Can easily do the division in C of PIC micro controller.
But is there a way to divide two number stored in two 8 bit registers.
For example look at this code.
I have to do it in PIC assembly for 8 bit Microcontrollers.

```
ORG 0H
R1 EQU 0X06
R2 EQU 0X07

MOVLW D'64'
MOVWF R1
MOVLW D'8'
MOVWF R2

; We want to Do R1/R2 We can assume that R1>R2 and we don't need Decimal Values
;SUGGESTIONS?

END
```

Comment: read http://www4.wittenberg.edu/academics/mathcomp/shelburne/comp255/notes/binarydivision.pdf  - "shift-test-restore" algorithm

Comment: If you need a higher performance division, write a C function using the `/` operator, compile it and "borrow" the assembly output...

Comment: You may well find the "assembly output" matches the code you would have written.  Particularly if the variables are declared unsigned.  But I think the OP simply has an assignment and not a design problem.  So this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need speed you can use 'repeated subtraction', essentially

```
Q = 0
while( R1 > R2 ){
   R1 = R1 - R2;
   Q = Q + 1;
}
```

I'll leave it to you to translate this to PIC assembly

Comment: Thank you very much i Transformed into Assembly and working perfectly.